# Updating a timeline

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm using twitter's API to search for tweets, and I want to be able to update the timeline.

According to ["Working with Timelines"](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/working-with-timelines), I need to pass the parameters `max_id` and `since_id` (ids of the first and last tweets), which I obtain with :

```
   var max_id = tweets.max_id_str;
   var since_id = tweets.results[tweets.results.length - 1].id_str;
```

But when I update I get the same tweets minus one. Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but what ?

Comment: How are you querying the API?
How are you constructing the url?

GET /1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi&max_id=X&since_id=Z

Comment: Jquery post() to a small php file, that configures and uses a library, themattharris-tmhOAuth

Comment: Note : I think it still uses version 1 of the API, since "count" is still called "rpp"